# Closed questions appearing in top results in Google

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, search

Sometimes, questions that don't strictly follow SO's rules get closed.

This is too bad imo, because some closed questions are still very useful and upvoted a lot, but cannot get any more answers.

The issue I want to address here is even more problematic: Sometimes **closed questions appear in the top results in Google**, presenting the user with dead threads with limited answers, **instead of better open questions**. As a result you spend a lot of time trying out poor old solutions, although there were threads with better solutions out there.

Shouldn't closed questions be hidden from search engines, or at least harder to find than open questions?

**To give an example:**

I was looking for a java UML diagram generator. Google showed me [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167266/generate-uml-class-diagram-from-java-project) as top result, with only disappointing answers (according to upvotes and comments), instead of presenting me with open questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302490/eclipse-plugin-for-generating-a-class-diagram), which had a much better answer.

Comment: The "still open" question could get closed though, for the same reason.

Comment: Also note the voting numbers on both questions...

Comment: Perhaps this shows you why questions asking for tool recommendations are off-topic...

Comment: The reason given against tool recommendation questions is the fear that it could "attract opinionated answers and spam". That does not always happen though. (In that particular example, that didn't seem to pose any problem.) When answers are objective enough and don't seem to be causing any harm, I think closing such valuable questions only diminishes the usefulness of the site.

What's more these questions could as well be phrased as "How to do something" to bypass the question-closing rule, and the answers will boil down to the same tool recommandations.

Comment: Example: 1st result for "Best C++ unit testing framework":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606793/state-of-the-art-c-unit-testing